# Mass update on selected Opportunity Line Items?

Tags: lightning, opportunity-lineitem, quickaction, workflowoutboundmessage, screen-flow

In Classic I have a functionality where you select a couple of line items in an opportunity and then press one of four buttons to update a checkbox in each of those items (which fields get updated depends on the button pressed). This is done to trigger an outbound message for the selected records and the checkbox itself "selects" which of the four messages is being sent. Now I wonder - how to do this in Lightning?

I've seen mass quick actions on e.g. cases that look pretty nice and could totally convert my four checkboxes into just one picklist with four values. But as far as I can see these are not available for line items. So - a different idea would be just to have a screen flow as I have it on the opportunity (the "easy way" to select the whole opportunity with all line items) - which works great - but I cannot figure out how to have a screen flow for multiple input records? (If this is possible at all.)

Surely there must be an easy way to update just one field on a selected amount of line items with the click of a button. Right? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out - this is surprisingly easy to do. You just need some undocumented as mentioned in this blog entry: [Submitting multiple records to Flows](https://www.xbaf.com/flow-list-buttons)

For this to work you basically only need to do three things:

1. You need to create an input text collection variable in the flow that is named `ids`.
2. For Lightning you just create a quick action for that flow on the `Opportunity`.
3. For Classic you create a list button on the `Opportunity Line Item` with an URL that links to your flow - e.g. `/flow/My_Flow`.

Et voilà! You can now have a flow that takes multiple ids as input and you can use the same flow in Lightning and in Classic.

Comment: What I haven't figured out yet is how I update multiple records with those `ids` in just one operation.